# EMPTY TABLE Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a strange problem with my MariaDB database. I create an empty table with the following code:

```
drop table if exists Subject;
CREATE TABLE Subject (
  id integer primary key auto_increment,
  code varchar(100) unique not null,
  name text not null
);
```

Query executed OK, 0 rows affected.

I try to insert some data into the table:

```
INSERT INTO Subject (id, code, name) VALUES
(0,'KMI/AIdb/PHW/15','Počítačový hardvér'),
(1,'KMI/AIdb/DBA/15','Tvorba databázových aplikácií'),
(2,'KMI/SPRVdb/INF/16','Informatika a základy správy databáz'),
(3,'KMI/AIdb/PR4/15','Programovanie 4 - Objektové programovanie'),
(4,'KMI/AIdb/DBS/15','Databázové informačné systémy');
```

Error in query (1062): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

If I run the same query one more time:

```
INSERT INTO Subject (id, code, name) VALUES
(0,'KMI/AIdb/PHW/15','Počítačový hardvér'),
(1,'KMI/AIdb/DBA/15','Tvorba databázových aplikácií'),
(2,'KMI/SPRVdb/INF/16','Informatika a základy správy databáz'),
(3,'KMI/AIdb/PR4/15','Programovanie 4 - Objektové programovanie'),
(4,'KMI/AIdb/DBS/15','Databázové informačné systémy');
```

Query executed OK, 5 rows affected.

I believe it has something to do with the auto_increment, but I have a huge database dump that I would like to insert. Is this a bug, or is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

**AUTO_INCREMENT** attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows.

You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers unless the **NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO** SQL mode is enabled.

[Read here for more details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 2):

The first insert created id=1.  This is because "0" (or `NULL`) is treated specially to mean "give me the next id".  Then the second row tried to explicitly insert id=1 and got a "duplicate".

Did your dump include a row with id=0, as you imply in a Comment.  That sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using id  autoincrement don't insert id

```
INSERT INTO Subject (code, name) VALUES
('KMI/AIdb/PHW/15','Počítačový hardvér'),
('KMI/AIdb/DBA/15','Tvorba databázových aplikácií'),
('KMI/SPRVdb/INF/16','Informatika a základy správy databáz'),
('KMI/AIdb/PR4/15','Programovanie 4 - Objektové programovanie'),
('KMI/AIdb/DBS/15','Databázové informačné systémy');
```

overall don't insert 0 for id

Comment: I must insert the ID because this is a database dump, and the id-s are cross referenced from other tables. If I just let auto_increment to do the job then the IDs won't match. Same goes for zero, if I remove ID zero, the cross references break. Why does it work the second time though?

Comment: then  you could alter the table (temporarly) revoking the auto increment so you can manage the id more easlly .. you can  add the autoincrement after the import of the dump is finished... but be sure you have not duplicated primary key